# Eclipse will not start with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: eclipse-cdt

When I start eclipse, the error log mentions:

```
SESSION Wed Jun 13 12:41:45 SRET 2018 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-06-13 12:41:45.433
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I tried the answeres of this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte) and checked all jar files, but still no luck. Please advise.

Comment: I tried the answeres in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte and checked all jar files. >Still no luck, please advise.